How can I resolve merge conflicts in a Gerrit merge commit without redoing the entire merge process?
I have two branches, A and B. I merged A into B, resolving numerous merge conflicts in the process. However, while I was working on the merge, branch B moved forward.
When I pushed my merge commit to branch B on Gerrit, I received a red "Merge Conflict" label, and Gerrit suggested that I perform a git rebase. The issue is that when I attempt the rebase, the entire merge process starts over, forcing me to re-resolve all the previous conflicts.
Is there a way to resolve only the new conflicts caused by changes to branch B without redoing the merge conflicts I already resolved? Any guidance or steps would be greatly appreciated.
I tried following the steps detailed here, but the commit is in this question is not a merge commit:
How to solve merge conflict in a approved review in gerrit?
When I'm doing these steps, git asks me to resolve the conflicts again.

Rebase, don't merge perhaps?

At what point do you mean? I'm trying to do a rebase now, but the conflicts I resolved earlier keep coming up.

Generally, rebasing is better for branches that contain ongoing development. The conflicts only need to be resolved once, when the base branch moves forward, not repeatedly. It also helps keeping your own commits simple, clean and complete. If you make three changes to one location and there is a conflict, you will have three conflicts, making things worse.

I ended up creating a temporary branch from the target branch (B). Then, I merged my original merge commit into the temporary branch, which re-applied the previous merge but only required me to resolve the new conflicts caused by updates to branch B. After resolving those conflicts and committing the changes, I switched back to the B branch and merged the updates from the temporary branch into it. Finally, I pushed the updated B branch to Gerrit, and the changes were successfully accepted.
